# Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The XML in file "/" is invalid: Element 'event': Missing child element(s)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

i am getting below error for magento 2.4 and it is working fine in magento 2.3

> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The XML in file
> "/var/www/html/magento240/app/code/PPPL/PhonePe/etc/frontend/events.xml"
> is invalid: Element 'event': Missing child element(s). Expected is (
> observer ). Line: 4 Verify the XML and try again. in
> /var/www/html/magento240/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:156
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/magento240/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(132)

**Please find the code for** `/var/www/html/magento240/app/code/PPPL/PhonePe/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd"><event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <!-- Do nothing -->
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't added observer name inside `<event>` tag.

You must have to declare `<observer>` tag inside `<event>` tag like below..

```
<observer name="observer_name" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\ObserverClass" />
```

Because it's **required**, You can check more details in below Schema file..

> vendor/magento/framework/Event/etc/events.xsd

Hope this will help you!